# Access to Google File Stream Files

Tags: files, stream

I have not found the way to access my files located in the File Stream Drive (Disc G:) that I have working in Windows while in ubuntu. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820531/mount-google-drive-and-dropbox-to-system-only-online, this https://askubuntu.com/questions/911717/how-can-i-access-my-google-drive-via-the-command-line-with-gnome-online-accounts and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086302/how-to-make-google-drive-folder-available-offlin. Any of this answers may contain useful information as you need.